# ProcessStartInfo working on one computer but not running on another

Tags: c#, pdf, processstartinfo

The following code is running fine on my computer but it hangs on office computer

```
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        info.Verb = "print";
        info.FileName = @"c:\temp\" + filename;
        info.CreateNoWindow = true;
        info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = info;
        p.Start();

        p.WaitForInputIdle();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        if (false == p.CloseMainWindow())
            p.Kill();
```

Please help

Comment: "Doesn't work" - how? Is the target file present on the office computer? Is there even a C:\temp folder? Does the user you are running as have rights to the file in C:\temp?

Comment: Folder is created and the file is also present but it hangs when it tries to run this code.

Comment: The process hangs? You've not got a printer settings dialog that isn't being shown?

Comment: yes but it hangs with windows busy icon and nothing happens the screen dulls and have to shut down the application.

Comment: Remove the "CreateNoWindow=true" line, and try it again, it may help you debug the problem.

Comment: The error it is giving is system.InvalidOperationException Process has exited so the requested information is not available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some computers are slower then others so the process is exiting before it is finished. Increasing the thread sleep time fixed the problem.